# Convert Google Doc to PDF using Google Script Editior

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, export-to-pdf

I've been trying to convert a Google Docs file to a PDF file without having to use the download option. Below is the script I have used in the Script Editor but it doesn't seem to work. I think the error is after the IF statement.

```js
function convertPDF() {
  doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  docblob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
  var result = DocumentApp.getUi().alert(
      'Save As PDF?',
      'Save current document (Name:'+doc.getName()+') as PDF',
      DocumentApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == DocumentApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    docblob.setName(doc.getName())
    folder.createFile(docblob);
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Your PDF has been converted to a PDF file.');
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Request has been cancelled.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

It is failing because the folder is not defined. If you replace it with DriveApp, the PDF will be created in the root folder and your function would work. You can also show the full URL in the message box.

```
function convertPDF() {
  doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Save As PDF?',
      'Save current document (Name:'+doc.getName()+'.pdf) as PDF',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    docblob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
    /* Add the PDF extension */
    docblob.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
    ui.alert('Your PDF file is available at ' + file.getUrl());
  } else {
    ui.alert('Request has been cancelled.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and explaining my error. Another question is it possible the saved file can be saved in the same folder as the file you are converting?

Answer (score 11):

To save the PDF in the original directory:

```
function convertPDF() {
  doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  // ADDED
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var docFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getParents().next().getId();
  // ADDED
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Save As PDF?',
      'Save current document (Name:'+doc.getName()+'.pdf) as PDF',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    docblob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
    /* Add the PDF extension */
    docblob.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
    // ADDED
    var fileId = file.getId();
    moveFileId(fileId, docFolder);
    // ADDED
    ui.alert('Your PDF file is available at ' + file.getUrl());
  } else {
    ui.alert('Request has been cancelled.');
  }
}
```

And add this generic function

```
function moveFileId(fileId, toFolderId) {
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
   var source_folder = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next();
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(toFolderId)
   folder.addFile(file);
   source_folder.removeFile(file);
}
```

Comment: I am using shared drive and I have an error in this row: var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);

Comment: very helpful answer, I did use the whole lot