# Export Google Doc URLs from a specific Google Sheet cell and convert to PDF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created a gs script to autofill certain information from G-Sheet to a G-Doc template (so to make the final G-Doc content more personalized).

I managed to write a script to create G-Doc url automatically once its autofilled. Now, I want to convert the G-Doc URL to PDF.

Please help!

**See below, the first column is where the G-Doc URL is automatically created, how do I do auto-create PDF URL on the second column?**

[columns where the URLs sit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Ppb.png)

here is the final part of the script for creating and saving G-doc URL:

```
 doc.saveAndClose();
 const url = doc.getUrl();
 sheet.getRange(index +1,154).setValue(url)
```

Comment: Here is another post that has a similar request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312992/convert-google-doc-to-pdf-using-google-script-editior  The only difference is that you would use DocumentApp.openByUrl(url) instead of getting the active.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
const docID = doc.getId();
const pdfURL = url.toString().replace("/open?id=" + docID, "/document/d/" + docID + "/export?format=pdf");
```

And just add the last line to specify where in the sheet you want to set the `pdfURL`